# NuGet adding rogue line to web.config MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget

Every time I install ANYTHING using Nuget, this gets added to my `<Runtime><asseblyBinding>` section in my web.config:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Obviously I'm using MVC4 so references to Razor 2.0.0.0 breaks things, and the following runtime error is thrown.

```
Could not load type 'System.Web.Razor.Parser.SyntaxTree.CodeSpan' from assembly 'System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
```

Its easy to fix, just remove the rouge section from Web.Config, but very annoying all the same!  Anyone know why this might be happening, or how to fix this?

I'm using Nuget Package Manager Version 1.7.30402.9028

Comment: Which version of NuGet Manager are you using?

Comment: question updated with Nuget version

Comment: Do you have references to the 3rd party RazorEngine package or anything that makes use of a wrapper around the Razor rendering core - such as libraries that allow you to use Razor templates to generate emails?

Comment: Yes I am using RazorEngine !!

Comment: I can confirm the same behaviour when having referenced RazorEngine! This is another bull.. from the Nuget team!

Answer (score 0):

Individual packages are able to provide installation routines written in PowerShell, which is probably what's happening here.  Does the same thing happen even if you install something unrelated to Razor, like, say, JQuery?

Thanks,
Clay

Comment: Happened to me while installing .less - keep having to comment this out every time packages are installed it seems